# Resizing UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

Using a `UIImagePickerController` in an iOS app (in Swift), I am having some trouble laying it out as I wish.

I want the `UIImagePickerController` to occupy the 90% top part of the display and keep the bootom 10% for another use.

Here the relevant code:

```
let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
……..
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
// Resize the UIImagePickerController to make room for other things:
imagePicker.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 0.9);
```

This indeed shrinks the dispaly used by the `UIImagePickerController` for displaying its list.
But the bottom 10% stays white and not usable by me.
If I place a view there it is covered when the `UIImagePickerController` appears.
Why is that? I am missing something.

Comment: I think the ImagePicker controller is actually on top and your view is behind the ImagePicker controller.

Comment: When you present the image picker modally, you are presenting it over your current view controller. You can modify how it's presented to allow you to still see the content behind it (set its modalPresentationStyle to overCurrentContext and set the nav controllers background color to clear), but you won't be able to interact with it. I'm not sure if you'd be able to add the image picker as a child view controller or not, but it may be worth a try.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't make any difference. My problem is that I don't seem to have any way to take control between the time the list appear and the time an item is chosen by the user and asked for `Select` or `Cancel`.